# $watch doesn't work when using the UI bootstrap(angular)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have problem when I want to using my select part with the "tab" in the UI-bootstrap.
The view part:
    
        請選擇全國稅基佔市價比例

```
<select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentTaipei" 
    ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
    <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
</select>

<select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentNewTaipei" 
    ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
    <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
</select>

<select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentTaichung" 
    ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
    <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
</select>

<select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentTainan" 
    ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
    <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
</select>

<select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentKaoshung" 
    ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
    <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
</select>
```

And the contorller:

```
$scope.$watch('selectTaxPercentTotal', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    alert(newValue);
    $scope.selectTaxPercentTaipei = newValue;
    $scope.selectTaxPercentNewTaipei = newValue;
    $scope.selectTaxPercentTaichung = newValue;
    $scope.selectTaxPercentTainan = newValue;
    $scope.selectTaxPercentKaoshung = newValue;
});
```

The fomer part can work well. When I select the options and give the value to ng-model

```
selectTaxPercentTotal
```

, the

```
scope.selectTaxPercentTaipei scope.selectTaxPercentNewTaipei       
scope.selectTaxPercentTaichung scope.selectTaxPercentTainan
scope.selectTaxPercentKaoshung
```

will all change value into the selectTaxPercentTotal

The problem occured when I using UI bootstrap with the "tab".

```
<tab heading="Total">
    <select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentTotal" 
        ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
        <option value="">請選擇全國稅基佔市價比例</option>
    </select>
</tab>

<tab heading="Taipei">
    <select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentTaipei" 
        ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
        <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
    </select>
</tab>

<tab heading="NewTaipei">
    <select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentNewTaipei" 
        ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
        <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
    </select>
</tab>

<tab heading="Taichung">
    <select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentTaichung" 
        ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
        <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
    </select>
</tab>

<tab heading="Tainan">
    <select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentTainan" 
        ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
        <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
    </select>
</tab>

<tab heading="Kaochung">
    <select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectTaxPercentKaoshung" 
        ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
        <option value="">請選擇稅基佔市價比例</option>
    </select>
</tab>

Then, the $watch doesn't works. Now I select the value for the ng-model="selectTaxPercentTotal", and the others can not change.

Someone can tell me how to modify my code?plz Orzzz
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tab` directive of ui-bootstrap will create a nested child scope for each tab, so a scope of each `<select>` tag will be different from a scope in the controller.

That why when you assign a value to `scope.selectTaxPercentTaipei` and friends, it has no effect.

To avoid this problem, you could use a dot-notation in bindings such as `model.selectTaxPercentTotal`:

```
<tab heading="Total">
    <select class="btn btn-default" ng-model="model.selectTaxPercentTotal" 
        ng-options="taxPercent.option for taxPercent in taxPercents">
        <option value="">請選擇全國稅基佔市價比例</option>
    </select>
</tab>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.model = {};

$scope.$watch('selectTaxPercentTotal', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.model.selectTaxPercentTaipei = newValue;
    $scope.model.selectTaxPercentNewTaipei = newValue;
    $scope.model.selectTaxPercentTaichung = newValue;
    $scope.model.selectTaxPercentTainan = newValue;
    $scope.model.selectTaxPercentKaoshung = newValue;
});
```

Hope this helps.